# How do I add letters prefix before my order number?

Tags: magento

all Im trying to add a few letters before the order number in magento, currently they are at default 100000001, 100000002, etc but I'm wanting something like,TD10000001, TD10000002, I've checked out several tutorials that say I need to edit the: `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Increment_Numeric` function but there doesn't seem to be a decent tutorial telling me how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered, found an awesome free plugin by [MSWebDesign](http://www.muenster-webdesign.net/) that allows prefixes before the order number exactly what I wanted, hope this helps anyone else.